# How do I return the middle of a python array?

Tags: python

Here is the prompt: 
On the first line display the first, last and middle element of the list separated by the , character.

I have been trying to get this figured out for a few hours now, but do not know the correct process to return the middle of the array. Here is my code so far:

```
primary = []
length = 0
i = ("MORE")
while i != "NOMORE":
    i = str(input("?"))
    print(i)
    if i == "NOMORE":
        break
    primary.append(i)
    length = length + 1
mid = (length/2)

print(primary[0]," , ", primary[-1]," , ",primary.pop([mid]))
```

The code works to get the correct inputs from the program, but as the lists will be variable lengths I assume some form of a loop will be used. The primary.pop([mid]) was my poor attempt at getting the median printed. I know that the mid will not be printed as it is the wrong variable type, but how would I replace this?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: A good place to start is the [python documentation on standard data types](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-list-tuple-range).

Comment: `length/2` will often return a float.  You should always use `//` for integer division if you are going to use the result to index a list

Comment: Please don't remove the text of the question you wrote; either delete it entirely or leave it so that others can learn from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're unnecessarily calling the `pop()` method on `primary` with `[mid]` when you should simply be indexing `primary` with `mid`. You should also use the `//` operator instead of `/` to obtain an integer value for the index. Since the index is 0-based, the mid point should be `(length - 1) // 2` instead:

```
primary = []
length = 0
i = ("MORE")
while i != "NOMORE":
    i = str(input("?"))
    print(i)
    if i == "NOMORE":
        break
    primary.append(i)
    length = length + 1
mid = (length - 1) // 2

print(primary[0]," , ", primary[-1]," , ",primary[mid])
```

Comment: (length - 1) // 2 would return the incorrect location for the prompt, (length -2) // 2 fixed this instead. Thank you for the help

Comment: You're welcome. I don't think `(length - 2) // 2` is correct though. Try entering `1`, `2`, `3`, and `NOMORE`. The expected output should be `1  ,  3  ,  2`, but with `(length - 2) // 2` the output is `1  ,  3  ,  1`.